# SQL Window aggregate function to hide repeating values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this query using window aggregate function in SQL Server.

```
SELECT customer,location, invoice_number, qty,
       Sum(qty) OVER ( PARTITION BY customer,location) AS sub_total  
  FROM myTable
```

The result shows as

```
  customer  location  invoice_number  qty  sub_total
    479249  441        800002309    -8.00  -20.00
    479249  441        800002310    -4.00  -20.00
    479249  441        800002311    -8.00  -20.00 
    481439  441        800003344    -1.00   -1.00 
    483553  441        800003001    -8.00  -19.50
    483553  441        800003001    -8.00  -19.50
    483553  441        800003001    -3.50  -19.50
```

But I would like it to hide the repeating subtotal as

```
  customer  location  invoice_number  qty  sub_total
    479249  441        800002309    -8.00  
    479249  441        800002310    -4.00  
    479249  441        800002311    -8.00  -20.00 
    481439  441        800003344    -1.00   -1.00 
    483553  441        800003001    -8.00  
    483553  441        800003001    -8.00  
    483553  441        800003001    -3.50  -19.50
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a complex `case` statement:

```
SELECT customer, location, invoice_number, qty,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by customer, location order by invoice_number desc) = 1 
             then Sum(qty) over (partition by customer, location)end) AS sub_total
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY customer, location, invoice_number;
```

The final `ORDER BY` is important.  SQL results sets represent *unordered* sets without an `ORDER BY`.  The data may look like it is in the right order, but that is not necessarily true unless explicitly declared as such.

Comment: Thanks, added `partition by` to the `over` and it works great.